# how do I send validation link to email address?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a php login system but it lacks to features. I would like to send activation link to a users email address before they log in, they have to click on a link to activate the account. I also would like to let them require new password in case they forget the one they have...everything else works fine except these two issues.how I do achieve that? thanks

**What I have in a table `users` in database:**

```
1   id          int(11)       AUTO_INCREMENT    
2   username    varchar(255)        
3   password    char(64)    
4   salt        char(16)    
5   email       varchar(255)
```

**register.php**

```
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
// If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { 
        echo "Please enter a username."; 
    } 

    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { 
        die("Please enter a password."); 
    } 

    // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
    // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see:
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
    } 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 


    if($row) 
    { 
        die("This username is already in use"); 
    } 

    // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
    // to ensure that it is unique. 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        die("This email address is already registered"); 
    } 

    // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
    // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
    // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt, 
            :email 
        ) 
    "; 

    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 


    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    } 


    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

    } 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 

?> 
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="" method="post"> 
Username:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="username"  required value="" /> 
<br /><br /> 
E-Mail:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="email" required value="" /> 
<br /><br /> 
Password:<br /> 
<input type="password" required  name="password" value="" /> 
<br /><br /> 
<input type="submit"  value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

$submitted_username = '';
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query against the database 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $login_ok = false; 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

    if($login_ok) 
    { 

        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 

        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

        // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
        header("Location: private.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to: private.php"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Tell the user they failed 
        print("The Username/Password is invalid."); 

        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
} 

?> 
<h1>Login</h1> 
<form action="login.php" method="post"> 
Username:<br /> 
<input type="text" name="username" required value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
<br /><br /> 
Password:<br /> 
<input type="password" name="password" value="" required /> 
<br /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form> 
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Before a user logs in, you need to send an activation link. right?

Comment: yeah doesn't it say that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general to validate an email what you need to do is upon registration create a random string; and store that string in your database with either the newly registered user's id or email address. Then along in your e-mail you send them a link that has that string attached. EX:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/activate.php?v=329857320952">Activate your account now</a>
```

Then when they go to that link you use $_GET['v'] to get that value from the link and check your database... you then search your database for that specific value and edit/delete the row  of the user connected with that value.

Which then brings you to two ways to keep a user registered after this takes place. You can either set a column perimeter value to 'registered' or '1' or pretty much anything; or you can delete the row that had that stored registration value...

Which means every-time a user logs in you need to check on either that new column value or if that user exists in the 'not_activated_yet' table. There are many ways to do this but this is a pretty basic procedure to follow.

Here are some basic scripts that can help you...
After a user meets all of your registration requirements near the php in which you put them in your database you can use this to email them...

```
<?php
$to = "$user_email";
 $subject = "Your Account Information!";
  $body = <<<EMAIL
Hello {$user_firstname} {$user_lastname}, here is your account information!

Username:{$user_username}
Password:{$user_pass}

Please activate your account by clicking the following activation link:
http://www.mywebsite.com/activate.php?aid={$aid}

EMAIL;

$headers = 'From: notify@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: notify@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
   echo("<p>Your account information was successfully sent to your email - ($user_email)!<br><br>Please open your email and click the activation link to activate your account.</p><br><p>If you do not see your account information in your inbox within 60 seconds please check your spam/junk folder.</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p> Unfortunately, your account information was <u>unsuccessfully</u> sent to your email - ($user_email).</p>");
  }
?>
```

As for changing passwords there are two different circumstances. One is that they know their old password and just want to change it... This is as simple as having a form where they enter their email, oldpassword, and newpassword... You check if in your database the entered password and email go with the same row... and if that is true you just run an UPDATE query to update their password field with a new one...

As for the password resetting the easiest method would probably be to have somewhere on the login page say forgot your password? With a link that redirects them to a page where they enter their email; and just like registration you send them an email with there. Then you store the unique key and user id... Once on that link they enter a new password; at which you find the table which the users id and temp-key were stored; then update the table password for that user id.

EDIT: Also if you want instead of all the setting temporary key stuff you could just send the e-mail to the password but assuming your passwords in your database are encrypted you would have to use a temp-key.

Forgot-Password Related Code (Part 1-sending):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
//generate a random string
/// insert the key and email into a row in some table of your choosing.
///send email to the email address with the code above.
///echo success so the user knows everything worked.
}
?>
<form action='' method='POST>
<input type='text' name='pass'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send Password Request'>
</form>
```

Part 2 Processing:

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key']; //gets key from the link you sent in your e-mail; what temporarily connects to that user.
// search your database table for that key
// once you have that users id delete the row in the password-request table and insert the password into your users table row.
?>
```

Comment: thanks bro but my code upon registration redirects the user to login php..I would very be glad if you edit my code according to your point also what about new password?

Comment: @Magna: No problem, and you can put this code where-ever you want it is just most convenient to put it right next to when you put them in your database. I will post a reset password code in a minute; I am grabbing the script off my old social networking website I made.

Comment: thanks again I already have the first one which let them change the password while knowing the old password..I just need new password when they forget the one they had..bzw I should put the above code in register.php..right?

Comment: @Magna: Yes you should put that email code right next to where you INSERT that user into your database table; and of course edit the text and variables to your case. Alright I will add some of the forgot-password related code; of course I assume I don't need to post the email part of that because I already showed how to do that.

Comment: yeah I can handle that now and many thanks.

Comment: @Magna: Alright, I just wanted to make sure to give you a general outline so you knew a simpler way to get everything done.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 2 fields say token and status to the users table. Now create a link adding this token at the end like (http://yourdomain.com/users/accountactivation/34gg456sas78ud) and send it in email.  When user hits this link, the control goes to the account activation where a query is run to verify if this token exists in the database. If yes, change that user's status to 1 and also change/remove the token from the table so that the link expires. When user logs in , check if user status is 1. If yes, user can login else a message is displayed to check email to activate account.